# Is it better to show label name from database or static pages?

Tags: performance, codeigniter, static

I have many label in my website and I am working with codeigniter!
My website has tree language, so the label title should change by changing language.

Now which way is better to keep higher performance for showing label title, from database or no just static pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep all labels in separate files like `english.php, spanish.php` etc. 
In that language file define all labels with relavent text as below.

In english.php

> define('WELCOME_MSG_GUEST','Welcome Guest!');

In spanish.php

> define('WELCOME_MSG_GUEST','Welcome Guest! in Spanish');

Based on the selected language, include or load the language file.

Then you can use label constant in view as

> echo WELCOME_MSG_GUEST;